# Adding an imagebutton to a gridView

Tags: android, gridview, imagebutton

I have a gridView and I want to have an imagebutton in the gridView that the user can press that will create another new view in the gridView. I'd prefer not to make all the gridView items have the same onClick method (because I am adding a drag-and-drop functionality that will use long click and because when I do this, even if I make the gridView "clickable=true", it still makes all my gridView items non-clickable) So I'm wondering how I can do this.

Here is the xml for the gridView:

```
<GridView 
android:id="@+id/GRIDVIEW1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:clickable="true"
 >   
</GridView>
```

and here is my custom adapter:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context Context;

// Keep all Images in array list
public ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

CheckBox mCheckBox=null;

// Constructor
public GridViewAdapter(Context c){
    Context = c;
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "Constructor is set");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern1);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "pattern1 added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern2);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "pattern2 added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.trashcan);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "trashcan added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "ic_launcher added");
}

public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkbox){
    mCheckBox=checkbox;
}

@Override
// How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter
public int getCount() {
    return drawables.size();
}

@Override
// Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
// data set
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drawables.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    boolean checked = (mCheckBox==null)?false:(((CheckBox)  mCheckBox).isChecked());
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
        view.setId(R.id.iconImageView_id);
    }
    if(checked == true){
        isSdReadable();
        Log.i("GridViewAdapter", "checkbox is checked");

    } else {
        Log.i("GridView", "Icons not for use/checkbox not checked");
    }

    /* view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView folder = new ImageView(Context);
            folder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

    });*/

    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}

}
```

Is there a way that I can put an imagebutton in the actual gridView and set up the onClick method the same as this:

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView folder = new ImageView(Context);
            folder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

    });*/
```

? I've tried looking around but I haven't really found anything that helps.

Also, I've tried adding in the "add_button" (the button I want the user to push to make a new view with the image as the ic_launcher) into the constructor but if I do that, how can I make it so that ONLY that first gridView item is clickable and will not affect the other imageViews?

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the same problem and i got this solution :

1)Create an interface in your adapter.

2)Declare a method in the interface.

3)In the onClickListener() of the image button call this method .

4)In your MainActivity write the functionality you want to implement in the method you declared in the interface.

OR

1)Create an Image View instead of an Image Button .

2)For the gridview write the onItemClickListener and inside the OnItemClicked write the intent.

3) Call this intent in the activity you want it to go with getIntent().

4) In the intent object us putExtra() method and pass whatever you want to pass from the current activity to next activity.

Hope this helps!!!